# Angular 6 paginator duplicating request and responses

Tags: angular, angular6

Im trying to create a search on a mat-table that has a paginator, when the component loads the functionality is as expected and when I click next page and look at network in developer tools, i see 1 request and 1 response, the issue comes in when I now search for something it still makes 1 request and 1 response but when i next page after i have searched for something i see it makes 2 requests and gets 2 responses so it duplicates and if i search again it makes 3 requests and responses after next paging so on and so on only once i click next page again but on each search still only 1 request and response.

Was wondering if someone could steer me in the right direct with this issue.

Heres my component

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import {MatDialogRef,MatDialog} from '@angular/material'
    import {MatPaginator, MatSort} from '@angular/material';
    import {merge, Observable, of as observableOf} from 'rxjs';
    import {catchError, map, startWith, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
    import {DataService} from '@app/providers'
    import {UserAdd} from '@app/modules/features/admininstration/pages/users/modals/user_add/user_add'
    import {UserEdit} from '@app/modules/features/admininstration/pages/users/modals/user_edit/user_edit'
    import {UserOtp} from '@app/modules/features/admininstration/pages/users/modals/user_otp/user_otp'
    import * as u from '@app/models/user'

    /**
     * @title Table retrieving data through HTTP
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'users',
      styleUrls: ['users.scss'],
      templateUrl: 'users.html',
    })
    export class Users implements OnInit {
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['username', 'firstname', 'surname','userrole','usertype', 'created','actions'];
      data: u.UserGrid[] = []
      search: string = "";
      resultsLength = 0;
      isLoadingResults = true;
      isRateLimitReached = false;

      userAdd: MatDialogRef<UserAdd>;
      userEdit: MatDialogRef<UserEdit>;
      userOtp: MatDialogRef<UserOtp>;

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

      constructor(private ds:DataService,private dialog:MatDialog) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
        this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
        this.sort.direction = 'asc';
        this.sort.active = 'firstname';
        this.loadGridData();
      }

      loadGridData(){

        merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
          .pipe(
            startWith({}),
            switchMap(() => {
              this.isLoadingResults = true;
              return this.ds!.getUsers(this.search,this.sort.active+'_'+this.sort.direction,10,this.paginator.pageIndex);
            }),
            map(data => {
              // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
              this.isLoadingResults = false;
              this.isRateLimitReached = false;
              this.resultsLength = data.count;
              return data.users;
            }),
            catchError(() => {
              this.isLoadingResults = false;
              this.isRateLimitReached = true;
              return observableOf([]);
            })
          ).subscribe(data => this.data = data); 
      }

      userSearch(){
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.loadGridData();
      }

      openUserAdd(){
        this.userAdd = this.dialog.open(UserAdd,{
          disableClose: false,
          width: '550px',
          height: '50%',
        })
      }

      openUserEdit(id:string){
        this.userEdit = this.dialog.open(UserEdit,{
          disableClose: false,
          width: '550px',
          height: '50%',
        })
        this.userEdit.componentInstance.id = id;
      }

      openUserOtp(){
        this.userOtp = this.dialog.open(UserOtp,{
          disableClose: false,
          width: '500px',
          height: '150px'
        })
      }

      deleteUser(id:string){
        this.ds.deleteUser(id).subscribe(()=>{
          this.loadGridData();
        });

      }
    }
```

And this is my template.

```
    <mat-toolbar color="accent" class="mini-toolbar" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <span>Users</span>

        <div fxLayout="row">
            <mat-form-field class="full-width" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <input placeholder="What are you looking for?" matInput [(ngModel)]="search" (keyup.enter)="userSearch()">
            </mat-form-field>
            <div fxFlex="10px"></div>
            <div class="custom_button" style="margin-top: 13px; width: 100px" fxLayoutAlign="center center" (keyup.enter)="userSearch()"
                (click)="userSearch()">
                SEARCH
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="10px"></div>
            <div class="custom_button" style="margin-top: 13px;width: 150px" fxLayoutAlign="center center" (click)="openUserAdd()">
                CREATE USER
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <div class="example-loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoadingResults || isRateLimitReached">
        <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
        <div class="example-rate-limit-reached" *ngIf="isRateLimitReached">
            Error retrieving data.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div fxLayout="row" class="sitegroup-container" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
        <div fxFlex="100%" class="data_container">


            <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table" matSort matSortActive="firstname" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">
                <!-- Username Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.username}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Firstname Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>Firstname</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.firstname}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Surname Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="surname">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>Surname</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.surname}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- UserROle Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="userrole">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>User Role</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.userRole}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- UserType Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="usertype">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>User Type</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.userType}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Created Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Created
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created | date}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Actions Column-->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>

                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
                            <button matTooltip="OTP" [matTooltipPosition]="'left'" mat-icon-button (click)="openUserOtp()" color="accent">
                                <mat-icon>smartphone</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            <button matTooltip="Edit" [matTooltipPosition]="'left'" mat-icon-button (click)="openUserEdit(row.id)" color="accent">
                                <mat-icon>create</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            <button matTooltip="Delete" [matTooltipPosition]="'left'" mat-icon-button (click)="deleteUser(row.id)" color="accent">
                                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
            <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="10"></mat-paginator>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: remember to unsubscribe to any observables in `OnDestroy`, otherwise the subscriptions will increment each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my userSearch function and added a refreshGrid function to just get the users and resultsLength instead of calling the loadGrid function so that i dont keep adding more subscriptions.

```
userSearch(){
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
    this.refreshGrid();
  }

refreshGrid(){
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.ds!.getUsers(this.search,this.sort.active+'_'+this.sort.direction,10,this.paginator.pageIndex).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.resultsLength = data.count;
      this.data = data.users;
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call loadGridData() you are subscribing to the observable build on your merge. You are doing this a few times through your code without removing the subscriptions ever. So adding or deleting a user is going to create a brand new subscription because you are calling loadGridData() again, increasing the amount of http calls you are making (older subscriptions will fire due to the changes on the chain).

There are a couple fundamental issues with the way you are doing your data load, I suggest you reevaluate this.

Some suggestions:

- Instead of using a direct subscription inside the backing code, put the result of your "load" into an observable property, bind that property on the template using "async".
- Move the code that does the http request into a subject, and have the mixed in your merge observable. Now, instead of calling the entire load, you can just have your subject emit the updated value and your UI should update.

If you use async then the Angular framework takes care of the subscription for you for the external observable (the one coming from the subject).

[NOTE - Replaced some commentary here with the example below instead]

Here is a naive example, hopefully that will show a method to avoid the continuously added calls.

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="loadData()">Refresh</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="currentTime$ | async as currentTime">
  <p>{{currentTime.currentFileTime}}</p>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentTime$ = new Subject<any>();
  private httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = http;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  public loadData() {
    const path = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now';

    const subscription = this.httpClient.get<any>(path).pipe(take(1), map((val) => val)).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.currentTime$.next(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        if (subscription && !subscription.closed) {
          subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So, this generates an http call everytime you press "Refresh", but older subscriptions are closed on completion. "take(1)" causes that completion to happen on the first get, thus making this behave the way I think you want your data to flow.